# How can I download my contacts with the latest LinkedIn application version?

Tags: iphone, applications

In the old (before version 4) LinkedIn application, there was a button to **Download all connections** to my iPhone.

In the latest (4.0.2) I cannot find that option.

How can I update (download) all my connections with the latest LinkedIn version?

Comment: **Update:** version 4.1 has restored this feature! Hooray!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that their [mobile app page](http://learn.linkedin.com/mobile/) doesn't show the current version, and the current version doesn't have this feature anywhere that I could find, I'm going to say that they have removed this feature.

Try using their [feedback page](http://m.linkedin.com/feedbacks/new) to request this feature in v4.x, or an explanation as to why it was removed etc..

Comment: Just checked with v4.0.3 as well as v4, didn't see this option.

Comment: Thanks for this, especially the feedback link. It would be pretty poor if they left this out: getting contact details is one of the big deals with linked in!